# If G has a unique subgroup H of a given (finite) Index, then Prove that H is characteristic subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know if a group G has a unique subgroup H of a given order then H is characteristic subgroup of G as every automorphism f on G order f(H) = order H .  But here H is unique subgroup of G of given index ( note that G may be infinite group) .  How can I proceed?

Comment: You just have to prove that $|G:H| = |f(G):f(H)|$, which is straightforward.

Comment: How this is straightforward?  Can you elaborate,  I can't see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: If $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\in G$ are representatives of the (left or right) cosets of $H$, then $f(g_1),\dots,f(g_n)$ are representatives of the cosets of $f(H)$.

Comment: Thank u,  I understand